# Issue regarding Android NDK 21d compatibility with Android 7

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools, pjsip

I have created pjsip library using Android NDK 21d and it was working good on Android 9 devices. But once i test with Android 7 devices , it start crashing app with below errors. Does that means NDK 21d doesnt support android 7 devices .. do i have to install lower ndk levels.

```
2020-07-30 11:26:15.914 1564-1564/org.pjsip.pjsua2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2020-07-30 11:26:15.914 1564-1564/org.pjsip.pjsua2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.pjsip.pjsua2, PID: 1564
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "__sendto_chk" referenced by "/data/app/org.pjsip.pjsua2-1/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so"...
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1567)
```

Comment: How are you building your native code? What is your `minSdkVersion`? Have you explicitly set `APP_PLATFORM` or `ANDROID_PLATFORM` and if so to what?

Comment: @Michael minimumsdk version 19 and never set APP_PLATFORM or ANDROID_PLATFORM. But i did set TARGET =android-28 as below in the code ...................................   ................................      ...............                                                                                             make OS=android NDKROOT=/home/james/Downloads/android-ndk-r20b TARGET=android-28  APP_ABI=arm64-v8a

Comment: Why is it set to android-28? Your native code must not use any features that aren't available on your minSdkVerion.

Comment: so i shouldnt set TARGET while building library . i have to keep it blank

Comment: You should probably set it to the same version as your minSdkVersion.